# Show content of huge txt/json file without extracting huge zip file

Tags: command-line, zip, extract

I got a zip file of ~400MB and within it there are certain txt/json files roughly in the range of 400MB - 1GB size.

I simply want to view first 100 lines of a target file without extracting it from the zip, without swamping out my memory.*(very low)*

Alternatively is there an option to split the target file in the zip, without extracting and doing it sequentially, i.e, when giving the `split` command with 50MB for eg, I only get the first split file, view it, then, continue the split for a second file, view it, continue for a third 50MB file, view it, again and again?

Comment: How much RAM? How much swap? Should be easy... open the zip file with the Archive Manager, and double-click on any txt/json file you wish to look at. Let me know if that works for you and I can make an answer for you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok the steps would be:

1. To get the name of the file in archive you wish to view it's content, list out the content (of the zip file ) with this command:

   ```
   unzip -l file.zip
   ```
2. Now to view the first `100` lines:

   ```
   unzip -c file.zip file/name_of_file_of_interest.json | head -100
   ```

**Note:**

1. This format

   ```
   unzip -c file.zip file/name_of_file_of_interest.json
   ```

   is needed, not

   ```
   unzip -c file.zip name_of_file_of_interest.json
   ```

   to get to the path to the file and this will be gotten when the command in `step 1` is run.

Example:

1. File `unzip -l wordpress-4.7.zip`, produces

   ```
    ...
    0  2016-12-06 19:40   wordpress/wp-includes/Text/Diff/Renderer/
    5535  2010-02-19 02:25   wordpress/wp-includes/Text/Diff/Renderer/inline.php
    6813  2015-06-28 16:27   wordpress/wp-includes/Text/Diff/Renderer.php
   12950  2015-06-28 16:27   wordpress/wp-includes/Text/Diff.php
   14460  2016-12-02 08:11   wordpress/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php
   34760  2016-12-01 03:19   wordpress/wp-includes/rest-api.php
   23621  2016-11-21 03:46   wordpress/wp-includes/update.php
   102116  2016-12-04 21:37   wordpress/wp-includes/comment.php
   14066  2016-08-25 18:37   wordpress/wp-includes/class-wp-text-diff-renderer-table.php
   2853  2015-12-16 10:58   wordpress/wp-config-sample.php
   ```
2. Now I want to see first `100` lines of the file `wp-config-sample.php` in `wordpress-4.7.zip`, so I do:

   ```
   unzip -p wordpress-4.7.zip wordpress/wp-config-sample.php | head -100
   ```

More information:

1. Why use `-p` option:

   ```
    -p     extract files to pipe (stdout).  Nothing but the file data is sent to stdout, and the files are  always
         extracted in binary format, just as they are stored (no conversions).
   ```

A more elagant output would be with `less`

```
less wordpress-4.7.zip

# OUTPUT

    Archive:  wordpress-4.7.zip
 Length   Method    Size  Cmpr    Date    Time   CRC-32   Name
--------  ------  ------- ---- ---------- ----- --------  ----
       0  Stored        0   0% 2016-12-06 19:40 00000000  wordpress/
   16250  Defl:X     4157  74% 2016-11-29 06:39 2b3bf692  wordpress/wp-settings.php
    3286  Defl:X     1397  58% 2015-05-24 18:26 e732ef29  wordpress/wp-cron.php
    1627  Defl:X      799  51% 2016-08-29 13:00 d0339e89  wordpress/wp-comments-post.php
    5447  Defl:X     2006  63% 2016-09-27 22:36 888ccd8b  wordpress/wp-activate.php
       0  Stored        0   0% 2016-12-06 19:40 00000000  wordpress/wp-admin/
    2401  Defl:X      933  61% 2016-10-24 05:45 1e03d7a9  wordpress/wp-admin/link-parse-opml.php
       0  Stored        0   0% 2016-12-06 19:40 00000000  wordpress/wp-admin/js/
   12000  Defl:X     3291  73% 2016-09-13 07:03 77f8b8cb  wordpress/wp-admin/js/editor.js
    6224  Defl:X     2215  64% 2016-11-03 06:40 693a34f0  wordpress/wp-admin/js/user-profile.min.js
    1508  Defl:X      640  58% 2015-07-27 12:19 ee45bde7  wordpress/wp-admin/js/word-count.min.js
    5148  Defl:X     2010  61% 2016-11-17 19:28 2384dae7  wordpress/wp-admin/js/tags-suggest.js
    6842  Defl:X     2399  65% 2016-10-23 19:16 41742fcd  wordpress/wp-admin/js/tags-box.js
   17717  Defl:X     5102  71% 2016-07-05 14:37 93dfd6b0  wordpress/wp-admin/js/image-edit.js
   34299  Defl:X     7077  79% 2016-11-04 18:18 97b89baa  wordpress/wp-admin/js/updates.min.js
    4192  Defl:X     1539  63% 2016-06-08 23:37 b8c4c822  wordpress/wp-admin/js/postbox.min.js
   20983  Defl:X     6187  71% 2016-11-03 06:40 3aec32c2  wordpress/wp-admin/js/nav-menu.min.js
   25330  Defl:X     7009  72% 2016-11-03 06:40 43591b6e  wordpress/wp-admin/js/theme.min.js
    1502  Defl:X      707  53% 2013-11-14 06:40 4dc0acc0  wordpress/wp-admin/js/custom-header.js
   11462  Defl:X     4344  62% 2016-11-03 06:40 0aa95325  wordpress/wp-admin/js/press-this.min.js
```

Comment: `-p` might be a better option that `-c` when viewing a single file.

Comment: It's amazing how unzip "knows" when to stop decompressing.

Comment: @RoVo I doubt it knows. It probably gets killed when `head` finishes reading and terminates, closing the pipe.

Comment: That's why i put " ;-)

Comment: What @muru said is how pipes normally work on *nix systems. It's just that most of the time, the right-hand side of the pipe consumes everything from the left-hand side.

Comment: The statement that the `file/` part of `unzip -c file.zip file/name_of_file_of_interest.json` is needed isn't really accurate; what's needed is to specify the full path to the file within the archive, because the archive (just like a file system) can contain multiple files with the same name which reside in different directories. I don't know how smart `unzip` is about figuring out which file you meant if there is only a single file with the given name within the archive's internal directory, but specifying the file by full path within the archive alleviates the problem entirely.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling I what I meant is that OP should copy the path from the output of `unzip -l  archive.zip` not that it has to be be in that format per say.

Comment: @George Is there a marker for `head 100`? If I had to output the contents `&>> output.txt`, 100 at a time till I am satisfied? Maybe read and output to file "line 1500 to 1600", etc and so on?

Comment: @arjun: In that case you may want to use an interactive text editor like `vim` and remove the part(s) that you don't want. This would require the entire file content to reside in memory. While `vim` can read buffer content from standard input it may be easier to extract the file to a tmpfs and open it like any other file.

Comment: @George  If not that then do you know about the second part of the question? What about splitting the file internally and then using `unzip`? Present answer makes it easy to get started to an extent, not quite robust.